# NUnit error while loading .dll which was build by CSharpCodeProvider

Tags: c#, testing, dll, nunit

Nunit-tool throws the following exception: **This assembly was not built with any known testing framework**

I have to build a .dll by CSharpCodeProvider like this:

```
public static void Main(string[] args)
{
  var provider = new CSharpCodeProvider();
  var options = new CompilerParameters
  {
     OutputAssembly = @"TestCases.dll"
  };

  string AssemblyTemplateClass= "public class AssemblyTemplate {}";
  provider.CompileAssemblyFromSource(options, new[] { source });
}
```

The AssemblyTemplate-Class looks like:

```
[TestFixture]
public class AssemblyTemplate
{
  [Test, TestCaseSource("TestSelection")]

  //Testing-Method

  public static String[] TestSelection()
  {
    var path = @"C:\Users\user\Desktop\TestCases.txt";
    return File.ReadAllLines(path);
  }
}
```

Within this Assembly class I´m using the NUnit framework. 
If I create an extra Class Library Project with this class, there is no error within NUnit-tool.
But I have to create a .dll programmatically during my application console.

Comment: What's the relationship between the `source` variable and the "AssemblyTemplate-Class"? Is your first snippet of code actually correct -- i.e. `AssemblyEmpty` is an empty class? If so, what is the second snippet of code used for?

Comment: I thought that the variable "source" in this context is used to get the class of which the assembly should be build? The second snipped of code is my class to build the assembly. It contains the code to get a file, which contains TestCases. With the help of this file, a .dll should be created. Sorry for no context. hope it helps.

Comment: I'm confused. Please post a [mcve], which someone can run to reproduce your problem.

Comment: I tried to add some information. Is it understoandable in this way?

Comment: OK, so if I fix "`source` isn't a valid variable" and run your code, of course it doesn't contain any unit tests. The only class it contains is one called `AssemblyTemplate`, and that doesn't have anything in it! It's as if you combined a project whose only file contained `public class AssemblyTemplate { }`. You're not using that second code snippet at all.

Comment: How could I fix this? My goal is the following: After generating a textfile with TestCases, I have to create a.dll out of it, in the moment the TestCase file was created. Is there a way to use the content of my AssemblyTemplate class? I never used it like this before, so I dont know how to achieve this.

Comment: Your `string AssemblyTemplateClass` variable needs to contain the actual code you want to compile

Comment: Including all using statements of the beginning? Or just the content which I posted?

Comment: How else would the `CSharpCodeProvider` know about them? Yes, the compiled needs to know everything that's needed for the code to compile.

Comment: Okay. But if I do this and add my whole class to the string, there is no .dll file created. The empty non-sense string created at least a.dll? Don´t get it, sorry.

Comment: You probably have a compiler error, since you haven't added a reference to the NUnit dlls, which are needed for the `Test`, etc, attributes. Look at the `CompilerResults` returned from `CompileAssemblyFromSource`

Comment: You are right, i got errors of missing assemblys. It seems like the compiler cant get the "using" references...sorry I am not into that. I dont know what to do.

Comment: No, you're missing the assembly references, as I said. It's the same as the "References" node in the Solution Explorer in Visual Studio. [See here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.codedom.compiler.compilerparameters.referencedassemblies?view=dotnet-plat-ext-3.1)

Comment: It cost me like the whole morning to run it properly...thank you a lot.